# Ignore PhpStorm region comment in versioning control

Tags: phpstorm

Is there a way to **ignore** this PhpStorm **region** code in a **versioning** code :

```
//region Constructor
/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->groups = new ArrayCollection;
}
//endregion
```

For resume just this 2 comment must be ignored :

```
//region ***********
//endregion
```

Region is a very useful for work but this is a IDE code which don't must in final versioning code. There is a way to use this with transparent method ?
*(Versioning code like SVN or Git)*

Comment: Do you want the code to be sent to the software versioning tool and in the same time ignored by PhpStorm? Do you want PhpStorm so that it ignore the comments in this region?

Comment: I want to commit the file but I want to ignore part of this file according to templating this region comment.